# How to unit test method with disposable objects in it

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, asp.net-web-api

I was having unit test about my controller which was looking like that:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var dummySeamlessCustomerRequest = CustomerControllerTestsHelper.CreateDummyCustomerRequest();
    var dummySeamlessCustomerResponse = CustomerControllerTestsHelper.CreateDummyCustomerResponse();

    _mockSeamlessService.Setup(s => s.GetSeamlessCustomerCallRequest(_controller.Request, "Credit Customer"))
        .Returns(new ModuleResultSet<SeamlessCustomerRequest>(HttpStatusCode.OK, null, dummySeamlessCustomerRequest));

    _mockAdapter.Setup(a => a.SendCreditCustomerCallToProvider(dummySeamlessCustomerRequest))
        .Returns(dummySeamlessCustomerResponse);

    //Act
    var actionResult = _controller.CreditCustomer();
    var expectedResponse = actionResult as ResponseMessageResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(expectedResponse);
    Assert.AreEqual(CustomerControllerTestsHelper.CreateSeamlessCustomerResponseString(dummySeamlessCustomerResponse),
        expectedResponse.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

My targeted method by the test is the following:

```
public override IHttpActionResult CreditCustomer()
{
    //...

    using (var response = new HttpResponseMessage())
    {

        //...
        return this.ResponseMessage(response);
    }
}
```

I left most important part of the method to me(if you think I should show more tell me but there are only some service calls that I mock in my test with ease.
Problem is that when I run my test I receive following error:

> Test Name:    Test
>   Test FullName:    ETIAdapter.Tests.Controllers.CustomerControllerTests.Test
>   Test Outcome: Failed
>   Test Duration:    0:00:00.005
>
> Result StackTrace:
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()
>   at ETIAdapter.Tests.Controllers.CustomerControllerTests.Test() in D:\Repositories\test_seamless-service\seamless-service\src\ETIAdapter.Tests\Controllers\CustomerControllerTests.cs:line 79
>   **Result Message: System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object.**
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.

I tried to search for solutions to test such methods but I couldn't find it. Most of the questions are about custom objects that implement `IDisposable` so they are mocking them , but I can't do that with `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: @dymanoid `ResponseMessage` method comes from the .NET Framework `ApiController` implementation.

Comment: Does this controller's method work fine outside test environment? OI mean if it returns 200 when making regular call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response message is wrapped in a using statement which will call dispose once the method goes out of scope. Remove the using statement

```
public override IHttpActionResult CreditCustomer() {
    //...

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    //...
    return this.ResponseMessage(response);

}
```

You are trying to manage code you do not control. The disposal of the response is managed by the framework. In this scenario there is no need to manage the `HttpResponseMessage` as the framework will dispose of it once the flow has been completed.

By trying to dispose of it yourself you are breaking the framework (which you do not control). The framework expects to get a valid response message and use it.

Comment: I know this but , doesn't this leave IDisposable object not disposed? I mean I know GC will eventually run and dispose them , but why not manage my object lifecycle myself when I can, because this will skip the GC finalizer calls which are pretty expensive or I am mistaken? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx

Comment: No it does not leave `IDisposable` object not disposed. The nature of `using` statement by design is to dispose of its target automatically once out of scope

Comment: Okay , so how do I test using statement scope? Because I really want to manage lifecycle of my object myself whenever I can and make less GC collections? Is it possible?

Comment: You are trying to manage code you do not control. The disposal of the response is managed by the framework. In this scenario there is no need to manage the `HttpResponseMessage` as the framework will dispose of it once the flow has been completed.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean I manage code I don't control? I create the response message and I return it this is pretty much the scope for my `HttpResponseMessage` why not dispose it myself? Also are you saying that this kind of practice is bad for controllers and request/response objects?

Comment: Just because you create an instance of `HttpResponseMessage` does not mean you control its code. You pass that object off to the framework which uses it for its normal operations. By trying to dispose of it yourself you are breaking the framework (which you do not control). The framework expects to get a response message and use it as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144831/discussion-between-kuskmen-and-nkosi).